# Spring Integration send message until a fire an custom event

Tags: spring-integration

I wan't to send some data to an external software that hava a proprietary communication protocol.

That's the abstract workflow.

**Sending Application events**

1. Send message
2. Wait for an ACK message
3. Process the ACK ( Report if something wrong in the message via return codes 
   in the ACK)
4. Send the next message

**Process an ACK**

1. Process the ACK
2. Report
3. Send ACK received event for unblock the sender so that the next message can 
   be send

So, which endpoint or channel is the right coice for that purpose ?

[SI - FLOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjYfJ.png)

Comment: Are your acks async or you just send and wait for ack? For later you just need to loop your messages over gateway. This way the caller thread is going to wait for the ack anyway.

Comment: That can be both. Depends on the situation. I am looking for a way like smart polling for inbound adapters. So I need wait for an ack event and do a rerty if the message can't send

Answer (score 0):

The retry is a part of the Outbound Channel Adapter when you try to send a message to the external service. See `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` and how to configure it in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#retry-advice).

For the waiting for ack task I would suggest to have an aggregator with the `MessageCountReleaseStrategy(2)` and some `CorrelationStrategy` which can group a request and ack for it. So, this way you won't leave an aggregator until ack has arrived.

This aggregator should be as a second subscriber to the `PublishSubscribeChannel`, where the first of is going to be your  Outbound Channel Adapter for sending the request to the external system.

Now the trick.

To block your sender until ack has arrived, you need to wrap the call to the `@MessagingGateway` and the answer (reply) should come from that aggregator.

I would suggest to make a `replyChannel` of the gateway as a `PublishSubscribeChannel` as well. This way the second subscriber would be your service activator to process ack from the released group in the aggregator. Meanwhile the first subscriber is a gateway per sen waiting for the reply.

The calling process won't be able to send the next message until the reply for the previous one.

I know this is complicated, but with your requirement to block send makes since too hard.

Comment: That look like to hard to maintain and to understand for my team colleagues. I make it simpler. I use custom created connections that use the subscribe and send methods of the channels. So I can manage the connections and the behaviuor myself and can use the channel flow of SI. Thanks.